# Swiftを使って写真を読み込むと、勝手に回転してしまう。

Tags: swift3, uiimage

photoLibraryから写真を取得して、UIImagePNGRepresentation()にてDATA型に変換後userDefaultsに保存。
userDefaultsからそのDATAを呼び出してUIImage(data:data)にてUIImageに変換後ボタンにイメージを設定すると、左に90度回転してしまうことがある。
全ての写真が回転するわけではないので、どう対処すればいいか分からないので、ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば教えて下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/97391

Comment: その`UIImage`インスタンスに対して、プロパティ[`imageOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624141-imageorientation)を取得し、調べてみてください。